# Integral solution given $x^2-dy^2 \equiv 1\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

It's given ($p$ is a prime): $$ x^2-dy^2 \equiv 1\pmod p $$
Using only this can we say $$ x^2-dy^2 = 1 $$ has always integral solution?

Comment: What is your quantifier? "For all primes p" or "For some prime p" ?

Comment: Assuming $d$ is a given integer and $x,y$ are unknown then $x^2-dy^2=1$ *always* has an integral solution, namely, $x=\pm1$, $y=0$. If $d$ is a square, that's the only solution. If $d\gt1$ is not a square, this is Pell's equation, and it is guaranteed to have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I do not understand the question. If it is from a book or notes, perhaps you could give more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If $=1 \pmod p$  actually means $\equiv \pmod p$,

$\implies x^2-1 \equiv dy^2 \pmod p$

Observe that if $p$ |LHS, $x≡±1 \pmod p$, then $p|dy^2$.

1. if $p∤d$ i.e., $(p,d)=1, p|y$ for accepting solution.
2. if $p|d$, any integral $y$ will give us integral solution.